# How does one do asymptotic analysis of code that uses JDK streams API?

Tags: java, java-stream, complexity-theory

In general I know that we have to look at the source code to understand the performance of code.

But more specifically this code times out in a competitive programming website.

This finds the frequency of occurrence of numbers from `0` to `100` in a stream.
The numbers in the array are between `0` and `100`.

```
    // Times out with int[] array containing 100000 elements.

    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i ++){
        l.add(array[i]);
    }

    int[] counts = new int[100];
    Arrays.stream(array).forEach( i -> counts[i] = Collections.frequency( l, i));
```

What is the Big-O analysis for this code ? I assume the culprit is the way I am using the Streams API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the Big-O analysis for this code ?

- There is no reason to think that the cost of `Arrays.stream()` itself scales with the size of the problem.
- `Stream.forEach()` is bounded by *n* * ***K***, where *n* is the size of the array and ***K*** is the asymptotic complexity of the lambda.  Your particular use will not shortcut the iteration, so there is no reason to expect a tighter bound
- Complexity of the lambda is driven by `Collections.frequency()`, which scales linearly with the size of the collection, also *n*, because it must scan the whole thing.

Overall, then, that makes for O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

The wastage here is in scanning the whole collection for every array element.  Since you expect there to be 1000 appearances of each value on average, that's very costly, and it scales with the number of array elements.  I suspect you intended instead to scan just once for every position in `count`, but even that would be pretty wasteful.  Can you think of a way to collect the frequency counts all in one pass?  Hint: don't overthink this.

Comment: You may be hinting that a simple `for` loop or `Arrays.stream(arr).forEach( i -> counts[i] = counts[i] + 1);` should be better, Can I know why you think `Array.stream` can't scale ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan, yes, the approach you describe in your comment is what I was thinking of.  Its efficiency is O(n), and you're not going to do any better than that for this problem.  When I said `Arrays.stream()` doesn't scale with the size of the problem, I meant that invoking that method costs `O(1)`, much like typical implementations of `Collection.iterator()` do.  It sets up a `Stream` object, but it doesn't have to perform any per-element work.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over all the elements of `array` (size 100000), while all you need to do is find the frequency of numbers 0 to 100(assuming exclusive) in the list that you've created, so iterate 100 times effectively as:

```
int[] counts = new int[100];
IntStream.range(0,100).forEach(i -> counts[i] = Collections.frequency(l,i));
```

---

By the way, if you're supposedly iterating through the entire array to convert it into a list, a simpler way to do things would be to count the occurrences of elements within the same loop as well.

```
int[] counts = new int[100];
for( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i ++){
    counts[array[i]]++; // same asssumption (array[i] < 100)
}
```

or stated in terms of streams

```
Arrays.stream(array).forEach(i -> counts[i]++);
```